# Having a stateful service layer while using mobx

Tags: flutter, dart, mobx

I am looking at using MobX for my flutter/dart application.

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget
{
  MyWidgetStore _store;
}

class MyWidgetStore extends Store
{
  // Listens to the events of the service to then pass them on to the widget via MobX
  ServiceLayerWithState _service;
}

class ServiceLayerWithState
{
  // this service layer class will be used in multiple widgets
  // Will send events when that state changes
}
```

The consensus on the internet seems that you write a store for the state of the application and share that store on multiple places.

Call me old fashioned, but I'm used to the MVVM model from C# and enjoy to have a Store (ViewModel) per widget instead.

Should I alter my view on where to store state and make all my services stateless? And instead put the state in the Store and share stores? Would there be a downside on the approach I am taking?

Answer (score 0):

flutter is a flexible framework you do not need to stick to particular architecture while development.

Mobx provides you the functionality of observer and can solve most use cases than other counter-parts.

If the state needs to maintain across the pages, keep it in APP Level state (Mobx/Redux/Provider etc..)  else for single page or widget use stateful widget and just setState is enough.

*“The rule of thumb is: Do whatever is less awkward.”*